# Is there a way to change default start frame on the timeline?

Tags: timeline, startup-file

I would like to change the default start frame fro 1 to 0, so that I wont have to set the start frame at 0 every time I open up blender.

[image]

Comment: Don't use Caps Lock please (it's called shouting)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open Blender, allowing your default startup file to load (so don't open an existing file).

Set the start frame to 0.

[image]

Save the file as your new startup file. Frame 0 will be the new start frame for all  new files created this way.